# Programatically Manipulate ListFilter in ExtJS 4.2

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am using many FiltersFeatures on my grid (ListFilter,DateFilter,StringFilter, etc.)  I cannot find how to manipulate these filters.  I would like to be able to "select" values in the List without making the user go into the menu and click it.

Per the below comments, I am unable to access the Filter itself...

```
grid.$className
"Ext.grid.Panel"

grid.filters.$className
"Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature"

grid.filters.getFilter("status")
undefined
```

My config for my grid and columns

```
    var filtersCfg = {
        ftype: 'filters',
        local: false,
        filters: [{
            type: 'string',
            dataIndex: 'service_number'
        }]
    };

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'Service',
        pageSize: 10,
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            format: 'json',
            url: '/services/list',
            extraParams: {order_id: Ext.get('services-panel').dom.dataset.orderId},
            idParam: 'dw_id',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'services',
                totalProperty: 'totalCount'
            }
        },
        remoteSort: true
    });

    grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        header: false,
        features: [filtersCfg],
        id: 'gridPanel',
        height: 335,
        frame: true,
        title: 'Services',
        store: store,
        bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
            store: store,
            displayInfo: true,
            displayMsg: 'Displaying services {0} - {1} of {2}',
            emptyMsg: "No services to display"
        }),            
        columns: [{
            header: 'Service #',
            locked: true,
            width: 85,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'service_number',
            renderer: function(value, meta, record){
                return '<a href="/services/' + record.data.dw_id + '">' +  value + '</a>';
            }
        }, {
            header: '',
            locked: true,
            width: 35,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'is_monitored',
            renderer: function(value, meta, record){
                if(value){return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></span>';}
            }
        }, {
            header: 'Status',
            width: 100,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'status',
            filter: {
                type: 'list',
                id: 'status_list',
                options: [<%= Service.uniq.pluck(:status).collect(&:to_json).sort.join(",") %>]
            }...
```

Comment: Perhaps you are calling `getFilter` before the filters themselves have been created. When exactly are you calling this method?

Comment: right now I am just calling through the console in Chrome.  The ultimate goal here is to have options for users to have "canned filters" that select multiple things.  Like "status = 'Active' and Start Date > one year ago".  If I can manipulate the filters through JS, I can accomplish these things without the user having to go through and use the somewhat cumbersome date filters.

Comment: through the console in Chrome *after the page has rendered*

Comment: I actually created a similar functionality in the application I'm working on right now. I used `getFilter` and it works for me. I still think you are calling the method before the filter objects exist.

Comment: Before calling `getValue` from the console, try opening a filter menu and filtering something. Then try calling `getValue`

Comment: getFilter returns undefined still.  I've tried the dataIndex, the label of the column,  the index of the column.  Nothing seems to help

Comment: Can you add the rest of the grid creation code? Specifically where you set the `features` config?

Comment: You could also put up a working jsfiddle.

Comment: As I understand it, you can add that externally OR in the config for the column.  In the example above, that is done all the way at the end.  I have also tried doing so in another config and applying to the grid as a "feature".  That resulted in the same behavior.

Comment: You MUST have the feature added to the grid. The optional part is how you add filters to the columns. You can define them all in an array within the feature definition, or you can add them individually in each column definition. Again, you must add the `FiltersFeature` as a feature to the grid, or it won't work at all.

Comment: OK.  I updated. I was including the FilterFeature already, trying it two different ways.  I guess that's why the whole thing worked.  Same results.  I updated the code above.

Comment: Through messing around with clicking the filter on and off, I have gotten a hold of the filter object.  That still doesn't help alot of I cant get a hold of it without manipulating the page.  Furthermore, I can only change String filter values.  The ListFilter responds the setValue and setActive(true) but the changes are not represented as selections in the list.  Have you seen this behavior?

Comment: I ended up rewriting a good chunk of the FiltersFeature, partly because I needed more functionality (like making a way to clear all filters, and make certain filters permanent so they can't be cleared), but also because the way it creates filters, and when it creates filters, is not done very well. As you have seen, it doesn't actually create the filters until you have interacted with them in the GUI. As for the ListFilter, I honestly can't remember if I got it to work with setValue before I rewrote it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your grid that is using the `FiltersFeature` is `grid`:

```
grid.filters.getFilter(dataIndexForFilterYouWant).setValue(newValue);
```

Similarly, you can use `getValue` to get the value of the filter, or `setActive` to make the filter active or inactive. Check out the docs for more info on the FiltersFeature: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature

or for more info on the filters themselves: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.filter.Filter

Comment: Please see edits above.  I ge undefined when calling GetFilter

Comment: I have been looking over those docs all day.  I try to only come here after a good few days of googling, contemplating, and reading the docs.